# Sum Case mysql contador erroneo

Tags: mysql, sum

Estoy tratando de contar unos resultados con sum case, pero me trae resultados incorrectos,
me trae id_user que no cumplen con la condicion de fecha

esta es la consulta

```
SELECT id_user,
 SUM(CASE WHEN  estado='RECUPERADO' and status_transito ='transito' and fecha 
 >= '2020-12-02' AND fecha <= '2020-12-09%'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 
   'recuperado'
 FROM transito 
  GROUP BY id_user
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los resultados que aparecen en cero no cumplen con la condicion de fecha, y sin embargo me los trae, le falta condicion a la consulta?

un ejemplo de registros que no cumple la condicion e igual lo muestra en cero
es el id_user 1022

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. Luego de tu `fecha <=` mira que la fecha tiene al final el signo `%` ¿es correcto así?

Comment: Si, es correcto asi RobertoLeOr.

Comment: Si le quitas el % sigue trayendo todos los registros en cero tambien

Comment: Saludos. Prueba (digamos) moviendo `and fecha 
 >= '2020-12-02' AND fecha <= '2020-12-09%'` luego del `FROM transito`; claro, el primer `and` no va, sería un `where`.

Comment: La consulta te va a traer todos los `id_user`, sumen 0 o no. Si quieres que algunos no se muestren, filtralos en un `where` o eventualmente agrega al final `having SUM(CASE WHEN  estado='RECUPERADO' and status_transito ='transito' and fecha  >= '2020-12-02' AND fecha <= '2020-12-09%'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >0` . Y por cierto lo de la fecha con el porcentaje no lo entiendo.

Comment: Gracias @RobertoLeOr era asi como tenia que modificar la consulta.